# How to put new_value in the appropriate place in a list in so that the list is sorted correctly in Python

Tags: python

I would like to create a function that takes in a list and a new_value. It will put the new_value at the appropriate place in the list.
Basically if the list = [3,7,8,11] and new_value = 7.9, then the output will be [3, 7, 7.9, 8, 11]

I have got two codes that look like this:

code 1:

```
    list_number_sorted = [3,7,8,11] 
def insert_at_asc_place(values,new_value):
        new_list = []
        for number in values:
            if new_value < number:
                new_list.append(number)
            elif new_value > number:
                new_list.append(new_value)
        return new_list
    print(insert_at_asc_place(list_number_sorted,7.9))
```

But this gives me the output [7.9 ,7.9, 8 , 11]

code 2:

```
    list_number_sorted = [3,7,8,11] 
    def insert_at_asc_place(values,new_value):
        new_list = []
        for number in values:
            if new_value > number:
                new_list.append(number)
            elif new_value < number:
                new_list.append(new_value)
        return new_list
    print(insert_at_asc_place(list_number_sorted,7.9))
```

But this gives me the output [3, 7, 7.9, 7.9]

Not quite sure what do to on fixing this, feels like I'm quite close.

Answer (score 2):

I have two options for you:

First, append the item to the list, then sort the new list:

```py
list_number_sorted = [3,7,8,11]
new_value = 7.9

list_number_sorted.append(new_value)
sorted(list_number_sorted)
```

Second, go through the items in order, inserting the new value appropriately:

```py
list_number_sorted = [3,7,8,11]
new_value = 7.9

for i, val in enumerate(list_number_sorted):
    if val > new_value:
        list_number_sorted.insert(i, new_value)
        break
else:
    list_number_sorted.append(new_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through list and if value is greater than previous and less than next value insert it in the middle with .insert(position, value)

```
lista = [3,7,8,11]
new_value=7.9

for index in range(len(lista)):
    if new_value>lista[index] and new_value<lista[index+1]:
        lista.insert(index+1,new_value)
        
print(lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were inserting the number everytime the number was greater/less than `new_value`. But you should only do it once, so i added a bool, which keeps track of it.

```
  def insert_at_asc_place(values, new_value):
        new_list = []
        appended = False
        for number in values:
            if number < new_value:
                new_list.append(number)
            elif number >= new_value:
                if not appended:
                    new_list.append(new_value)
                    appended = True
                new_list.append(number)
        return new_list
```

or much simpler as a list comprehension:

```
def insert_at_asc_place(values, new_value):
    return [a for a in values if a < new_value] + [new_value] + [b for b in values if b >= new_value]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy and efficient way:

```
from bisect import insort as insert_at_asc_place
```